# Can I Flash Ubuntu Touch to Wiko Cink Slim

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

I was wondering if I can flash **Ubuntu touch** on my **Wiko Cink Slim** android phone.

**Specs:**

•Dual SIM/ Dual Standby
 •4.0-inch WVGA (480x800) IPS Display
 •233ppi with 5-point multi-touch feature
 •Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)
 •1GHz dual-core MT6577 processor
 •PowerVR SGX531 GPU
 •512MB of RAM
 •4GB of internal storage (2.5GB usable)
 •microSD card slot up to 32GB
 •5MP autofocus camera with LED flash
 •720p HD video recording
 •VGA (0.3MP) front camera
 •HSDPA 7.2 Mbps; HSUPA 5.76 Mbps
 •Bluetooth v2.1 with A2DP and EDR
 •WiFI 802.11b/g/n, WiFi HotSpot
 •GSM Triband / 3G Dualband
 •GPS with A-GPS support
 •TV-Out support / LED Notification
 •3.5mm headset jack / microUSB
 •Proximity / Ambient light / Motion Sensor
 •Li-ion 1,600mAh battery
 •Standby time up to 200 hours
 •Talk time up to 9 hours
 •127.5 x 65.5 x 10.3mm (dimension)
 •125g (weight)

Comment: Is this something like an advertisement for the phone model?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is not in [this list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) (and I don't see it) you can try to do a port by yourself, following [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting), or asking to someone on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com)